# custom login page instead of simplesamlphp IDP login page

Tags: php, saml, simplesamlphp

We built Simplesamlphp IDP, that transferred data to sp as per the procedure. Its going good. Now we want to implement our site login page instead of the IDP default login page. 
How to implement the option on Simplesamlphp IDP setting ? OR
Shall i achieve that by set any extra sessions on site login process?

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer, I have passed the my session username and password details. its work well.

Comment: Ergh - this is the worst! Why wouldn't you share how you did it?

Comment: I updated the answer. I have passed the username and password details by session values.